# Checking up on a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`

Tags: python, concurrency, introspection, concurrent.futures

I've got a live `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. I want to check its status. I want to know how many threads there are, how many are handling tasks and which tasks, how many are free, and which tasks are in the queue. How can I find out these things?

Comment: I don't believe those operations are part of the API. You will likely have to did into the source to poke at those internals: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py

Comment: Right now there's no way to tell which threads are busy. There's a TODO in the code that notes that ability should be added so that new threads aren't created to handle tasks if there are already idle threads which could handle them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is some visibility into the Pool, and the pending workitem queue. To find out what's available, print `poolx.__dict__` to see the structure.  Read the ThreadPool code, it's pretty good: [concurrent.futures.thread](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#l42)

The following creates a pool with one thread. It then creates two jobs: one sleeps for 3 seconds, the other immediately returns.  The pool's number of pending work items is then printed.

Following that, we print out items from the work queue.  In this case, a thread is already executing the `time.sleep(3)` function, so that's not in the queue. The function `sleep` with args `[0]` and kwargs `{}` is printed, because that's the next work item for the pool to run.

Kudos to @dano for the nondestructive queue insight, and @abarnert.

### source

```
import concurrent.futures, time

poolx = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
poolx.submit(time.sleep, 3)
poolx.submit(time.sleep, 0)   # very fast

print('pending:', poolx._work_queue.qsize(), 'jobs')
print('threads:', len(poolx._threads))
print()

# TODO: make thread safe; work on copy of queue?
print('Estimated Pending Work Queue:')
for num,item in enumerate(poolx._work_queue.queue):
    print('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format(
        num+1, item.fn, item.args, item.kwargs,
        ))

poolx.shutdown(wait=False)
```

### output

```
pending: 1 jobs
threads: 1

Pending Work Queue:
1   <built-in function sleep>   (0,)    {}
```

Comment: You can check what's in the queue without destroying it : `for item in poolx._work_queue.queue: print(item.fn, item.args, item.kwargs)`.

Comment: Woo thanks again @dano -- I've updated the code and description to add your insight.

Comment: This isn't thread safe. The `pool._work_queue` part is fine, but iterating over `pool._work_queue.queue` is not. That queue member is only supposed to be used with appropriate synchronization; your iterator could be invalidated at any point by another thread pushing or popping. You'll probably _usually_ get away with it in CPython in low-contention scenarios, but with a GIL-less implementation or high contention (i.e., exactly the cases you really need a queue) it'll fail.

Comment: It seems like getting the queue size should be at least safe, which is enough to answer about 75% of the question... But to know what's queued, you really need to explicitly hand it a safely-iterable queue, not use the one in queue.Queue.

Comment: @abarnert I suppose you could just acquire `pool._work_queue.mutex` prior to iterating over it. That's all `queue.Queue` uses for synchronization.

Comment: @dano: If you only care about CPython, and only a specific range of versions you've checked, then yeah. But for other implementations, you may need to do something different—or it may just not be possible. (If Jython or Iron wraps a JVM or .NET lock-free queue, for example—which would be a good idea, but I don't know if they actually do—this either won't be impossible at all, or will have to be written very differently…)

Comment: @shavenwarthog: I don't know that "work on copy of queue" would help here. Is there a synchronized copy operation? If not, it'll just shrink your race condition, making it harder to debug, without eliminating it.

Comment: anybody know what version of python this covers?  I'm trying it now and getting an attribute error on <threadpool>._work_queue.queue.  AttributeError: '_queue.SimpleQueue' object has no attribute 'queue'

Answer (score 0):

Nor very clean and reliable way to find `pending` futures, but I do it like this:

```py
if 'state=pending' in str(future):
    logger.debug('PENDING')
elif future.running():
    logger.debug('RUNNING')
elif future.cancelled():
    logger.debug('CANCELLED')
elif future.exception():
    logger.debug('EXCEPTION')
elif future.done():
    logger.debug('DONE')
```